# Can't get Samba smv.conf shadow copy snapprefix to recognise snaps

Tags: samba, regex, snapshot, shadow-copies

I'm really with this one. What I'm aiming for is that snpshots with an optional tag at the front, as well as untagged snaps are seen in windows as previous copies, e.g. file names such as:

```
/mnt/pool1/.snapshots/Backup/GMT-2023.07.16-12.53.26
/mnt/pool1/.snapshots/Backup/Sometagname_GMT-2023.07.16-12.53.26
/mnt/pool1/.snapshots/Backup/anothertagname23_GMT-2023.07.16-12.53.26
```

If I set the smb.conf up as follows the untagged shadow copies are seen by windows as expected.

```
shadow:snapdir = /mnt/pool1/.snapshots/Backup
shadow:basedir = /mnt/pool1/Backup  
shadow:sort = desc
shadow:format = GMT-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
shadow:localtime = yes
```

I've tried every combination of regex and setting I can imagine but I can't find values for **shadow:snapprefix** and **shadow:delimiter** that achieve this. Here are some combinations I've tried for example:

```
shadow:format = %Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
shadow:localtime = yes
shadow:snapprefix = ^[A-Za-z0-9]\{0,\}\(_\)\{0,1\}\(GM\)\{1\}
shadow:delimiter = T-
shadow:format = %Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S

shadow:format = GMT-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
shadow:localtime = yes
shadow:snapprefix = ^[A-Za-z0-9]*\(_\)?
shadow:delimiter = GMT-
shadow:format = GMT-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
```

Any help would be really appretiated as I've already spent several hours working through combinations and searching on line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time on this and finally got to a solution. Details are here:https://github.com/ArthurMitchell42/BTRFS_Snapshots including an example script to generate he snapshots in the correct way.

The key settings for smbd.conf are:

```
[global]
   vfs object = recycle shadow_copy2 btrfs fruit cap catia

   recycle:repository = /mnt/pool1/%S/.recycle/%U 
   recycle:touch = Yes 
   recycle:keeptree = Yes 
   recycle:versions = Yes 
   recycle:noversions = *.tmp,*.temp,*.o,*.obj,*.TMP,*.TEMP 
   recycle:exclude = *.tmp,*.temp,*.o,*.obj,*.TMP,*.TEMP 
   recycle:excludedir = /.recycle,/tmp,/temp,/TMP,/TEMP 

;   shadow:localtime = yes
   shadow:sort = desc
   shadow:format = GMT-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
   shadow:snapprefix = ^[A-Za-z0-9_]\{0,\}$
   shadow:delimiter = GMT-
```

**NOTE** shadow:localtime *must* be commented out or you will see nothing
and in each share:

```
[Media]
   path = /mnt/pool1/Media
   shadow:snapdir = /mnt/pool1/.snapshots/Media
   shadow:basedir = /mnt/pool1/Media
    comment = Music, video and books
    writeable = yes 
    delete readonly = yes 
    browseable = yes
;    recycle:exclude = *,*.*,.*,.*.*
```